# How to get in-order sorted array from binary search tree? (in C++)

Tags: c++, oop

In `C++`, how do we implement a method that returns an inorder sorted array from ?

```
node * inorder(node *n, int a[], int *index){
//Implement this function to sort the given array in the main function
    if(n == NULL){
        return NULL;
    }
    inorder(n->left, a, index);
    cout << n->data << " ";
    inorder(n->right, a, index);
}
```

This auto prints the tree,
but I need this function to sort the array (given in main function).

Comment: Don't use `NULL` in C++. It has been obsoleted by the keyword `nullptr`.

Comment: Please show a [mre] containing a filled binary search tree. Then show the desired output/result and contrast it to the result of the shown code. Generally please take the [tour] and read [ask]. You need to be more clear about what part of your goal got you stuck. The sorting via traversal seems to be clear. Is it about how to  return an array? Or about how to create one? Or how to fill one?

Comment: instead of cout, use ans.push_back(node->data). here node is n and ans is the array in which you need to return the data, which may be `a` but your qsn doesn't provide clarification about `a`. And what is `index` used for?

Answer (score 0):

You should use the following code for sorting

```
    void store-sorted(Node *root, int arr[], int &i){
    if (root != NULL)
    {
        store-sorted(root->left, arr, i);
        arr[i++] = root->key;
        store-sorted(root->right, arr, i);
    }}
    void tree-sort(int arr[], int n){
    struct Node *root = NULL;
    root = insert(root, arr[0]);
    for (int i=1; i<n; i++)
        root = insert(root, arr[i]);
    int i = 0;
    store-sorted(root, arr, i);
}
```